# How can content be copied between Locales in Silverstripe Fluent?

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

We are working on a Silverstripe project with a relatively complex data model.

We have around 30 types of Data Object which need to be translatable via the [Fluent module](https://github.com/tractorcow-farm/silverstripe-fluent).

The production CMS will have 3-6 Locales & I am trying to work out how we can provide support for CMS users to make the content management as easy as possible.

Specifically is there a way to enable the following functionality in the CMS:

1. Copy the fields from one Locale to another Locale on a specific Data Object or Record?
2. Copy all of the fields from one Locale to another Locale across all records?

The default behaviour appears to be that content can only be copied across Locales manually, which would be overwhelming for the size/ complexity of the data.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: 1) There is the concept of a fallback locale, see https://github.com/tractorcow-farm/silverstripe-fluent/blob/master/docs/en/scenarios.md
2) In fluent you can define which fields to translate; all other fields are the same in all locales. Is this what you need?